# Odd date formatting string error c#

Tags: asp.net, datetime, label, string-formatting

I have a web application, and I have a label that is pulling a date from the db and displaying it.  The date should be displayed "7/21/2011" but instead it is displaying as "July, 21 2011 12:00 AM"

I am formatting the string using the following eval statement -

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" Text='<%#Eval("dtmAward", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' />
```

What would make this date format in a long text date form, instead of a conventional date?  Everywhere else I use that eval statement (with other dates from the db) it formats correctly.

Comment: I smell a typo or copy/paste error somewhere in your code/code-behind. Are you positive this is the ONLY place that this label is getting data from? Is anything else touching it anywhere? Search your code for lblDate. Also, be sure dtmAward is truly a date, and not a text string.

Comment: Are you casting or converting the date to string somewhere in the stored procedure or query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a hunch, but however you're binding the data, that column being specified as a DateTime type? If it's just specified as a string, I can imagine it doesn't get formatted.

Comment: Great catch, it was buried deep down and being converted to a string when it came from the db..  Thanks!